# PdfMake: function getBase64 return undefined value

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, promise, pdfmake

I am generating a Pdf-file with **PdfMake** and encode this in **base64** string array with the method `getBase46()` like this:

```
 let base64: string;

 this.pdf.createPdf(buildPdf(pdfModel)).getBase64(
      function(encodedString) {
        base64 = encodedString;
        console.log(base64); // base64 is not undefined and is a some string
      }
 );

 console.log(base64); // base64 is undefined here
```

How can I get the variable `base64` outside the `function`?

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved it by binding the actual **context** (`this`) of my Class to the context of the callback `function`, so that the var `base64` can also be set at the end of the call:

```
    let base64: string;

    this.pdf.createPdf(buildPdf(pdfModel)).getBase64(
        function(encodedString) {
           base64 = encodedString;
           console.log(this.base64); // this.base64 refers to var on the top
        }.bind(this) // To bind the callback with the actual context
    );
```

Comment: can also see here for other explanations:  ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) and the official doc of Typescript: (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is an asynchronous operation, you can only guarantee that the value will be defined inside the callback function.

Comment: It means there is no option to get the string outside the callback ? @mcrvaz

Comment: Ideally you should be using promises, but either way the string would only be defined inside the "then".
You must execute your operations inside that function.